# Pandas Dataframe Tabs and Whitespace Trim

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm reading a .csv file into a pandas dataframe.  I read the file as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t')
```

The text headers look like (\s spaces \t tab)

`Date\s\s\tPlace\s\s\s\s\s\tLow\s\s\s\s\tHigh\s\s\s\s\t`

I'm using the '\t' sep to read in the file into a dataframe.  But the problem is if I try to access one of the columns using df['Date'] I get a KeyError: 'Date'.  I think there are white-spaces and maybe tabs too that pandas doesn't strip when reading the columns? How can I remove the white spaces and tabs from the column headers?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delim_whitespace=True)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use `.str.strip`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it.